# Convert Single JSON Object within JSON document to an Array with jq

Tags: json, jq

Tryin to use jq to make a slight transformation in a JSON document I am working with.

I am using this as sample input JSON:

```js
{"root" : {"to" : {"email" : "some-email1@gmail.com"}, "dynamic_template_data" : {"FIRSTNAME" : "BLANCA", "last_4" : "9999", "OFFERCODE" : "88888888888888888"}}}
{"root" : {"to" : {"email" : "some-other-email1@gmail.com"}, "dynamic_template_data" : {"FIRSTNAME" : "Michael", "last_4" : "8888", "OFFERCODE" : "9999999999999999999999"}}}
```

At the moment, I am using this jq filter to try to transform the JSON (also specifying slurp option):

> jq --slurp '{"template_id":"d-34d9948687504d1f91fa9ddb738e94c0","asm":{"group_id":14817},"categories":["PROD","ICAP"],"personalizations": [.[].root],"from" : {"email" : "offers@bankoftheworld.com", "name" : "Bank of the World"}, "reply_to" : {"email" : "noreply@bankofthworld.com", "name" : "Bank of the World"}}'

...which returns close to what I need below with the "to" element to be an array containing the email address:

```js
{
  "template_id": "d-34d9948687504d1f91fa9ddb738e94c0",
  "asm": {
    "group_id": 14817
  },
  "categories": [
    "PROD",
    "ICAP"
  ],
  "personalizations": [
    {
      "to": {
        "email": "some-email1@gmail.com"
      },
      "dynamic_template_data": {
        "FIRSTNAME": "BLANCA",
        "last_4": "9999",
        "OFFERCODE": "88888888888888888"
      }
    },
    {
      "to": {
        "email": "some-other-email1@gmail.com"
      },
      "dynamic_template_data": {
        "FIRSTNAME": "Michael",
        "last_4": "8888",
        "OFFERCODE": "9999999999999999999999"
      }
    }
  ],
  "from": {
    "email": "offers@bankoftheworld.com",
    "name": "Bank of the World"
  },
  "reply_to": {
    "email": "noreply@bankofthworld.com",
    "name": "Bank of the World"
  }
}
```

...but the email address is not returning in an array as I need.

Desired output:

```js
{
"template_id": "d-34d9948687504d1f91fa9ddb738e94c0",
"asm": {"group_id": 14817},
"categories": [
    "PROD",
    "ICAP"
],
"personalizations": [
    {
        "to": [
            {"email": "some-email1@gmail.com"}
        ],
        "dynamic_template_data": {
            "FIRSTNAME": "BLANCA",
            "last_4": "9999",
            "OFFERCODE": "88888888888888888"
        }
    },
    {
        "to": [
            {"email": "some-other-email1@gmail.com"}
        ],
        "dynamic_template_data": {
            "FIRSTNAME": "Michael",
            "last_4": "8888",
            "OFFERCODE": "9999999999999999999999"
        }
    }
],
"from": {
    "email": "offers@bankoftheworld.com",
    "name": "Bank of the World"
},
"reply_to": {
    "email": "noreply@bankofthworld.com",
    "name": "Bank of the World"
}
}
```

Comment: Your desired output is invalid json. You can check it here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `.to` with `[.to]`

```
jq --slurp '{"personalizations": [.[].root | .to = [.to]]}'
```